# Matlab. One script cell returns two figures

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm trying to make a scriptfile with various script cells in it, separated by `%%`. The following code, returns one an old figure and one circle. However I want to clear the figure window so I only get one figure when I execute one particular script.

```
% Rita tan(x)
x=((-pi/2)+0.01:0.01:(pi/2)-0.01);
y=tan(x);
plot(x,y)
grid on
%%
% Exempel 1
x=linspace(0,8);
y=x.*sin(x);
plot(x,y)
title('f(x)=sin(x)')
%%
% Plot circle
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
x=cos(t); y=sin(t);
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y)
title('Utan axis equal')
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,y)
axis equal
title('Med axis equal')
%%
% Funktionsytor
x=linspace(0,5,50);
y=linspace(0,5,50);
[X,Y]= meshgrid(x,y);
F=X.*cos(2*X).*sin(Y);
surf(X,Y,F)
%%
```

What I get is:

[image]

How do I get only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`clf`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) (clear figure) to delete all graphic objects from the current figure. Since it seems likely that you'd be executing scripts in random order, so use `clf` at the beginning of each section for the stated reason.
If you're executing the script in the same sequence as shown in the question then you can just add `clf` at the start of the section after subplots.

Comment: Oh God... I've been pressing RUN instead of RUN SECTION... I'm so sorry... but thanks a lot for the codes it really helped me a lot buddy. Getting late...

Answer (score 2):

When the last section is executed, the axes defined by the command `subplot(1,2,2)` is still the [current axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html), so that is where your next plot is added. You can [close the previous (i.e. current) figure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) at the beginning of that last section so that a new figure and axes is created for the next plot:

```
% Funktionsytor
close(gcf);
x=linspace(0,5,50);
...
```

In general, when dealing with a lot of different [figures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) or [axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html), best practice dictates that you should [store unique handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) for each of them. That way you can specifically modify/close them as needed. For example, you could plot your two subplots in two separate figures like so:

```
%%
% Plot circle

t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);

hFigure1 = figure();  % Create first figure
plot(x, y);           % Plot to axes in first figure
title('Utan axis equal');

hFigure2 = figure();  % Create second figure
plot(x, y);           % Plot to axes in second figure
axis equal;
title('Med axis equal');
```

Now, you can close either one, or both, as needed later in your code:

```
close(hFigure1);  % Closes the first figure, second still exists
```

Comment: where do I add that command? I just entered it in the command window but it just clsoed the figure window. Then I ran the script but still same result.

Comment: @Parseval: You add it on the line after `% Funktionsytor`.

Comment: So now I only get the plot of the last script, but how can I only get the plot of the circle script above?

Comment: @Parseval: If you only want to plot the circle, why are you using [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) to make multiple plots per figure?

Comment: I only want two plots for the circle scripts with two different titels,

Comment: @Parseval Aren't you executing one code block at a time?

Comment: Yes, exactly, one cell at a time. I'm really sorry If I'm confusing the hell out of you guys, I'm very new to this and trying to follow instructions on a PDF file I got from the uni.

Comment: But why can't I still use subplot? I want to plot both of the graphs at the same time when I run the script.

Comment: @Parseval: Then just plot it like you did before, but create a new figure for each section so you aren't overwriting any old figures from previous sections.

Comment: But i thought the command `plot` creates new figures? Doesnt the `%%` make sure that previous figures used by previous cells can't overwrite anything?

Comment: @Parseval: [This documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preparing-figures-and-axes-for-graphics.html) might help you better understand what is going on.